# React Native App Not Displaying console.logs()

Tags: react-native

After releasing my app for production, I found I wasn't able to view console.logs() anymore no matter what I attempted.

I attempted to reproduce the problem:

1. Installed latest version of npm
2. Used `create-react-native-app` to create a new app.
3. Added simple button to call a console.log()
4. Console.log() worked in IOS Simulator
5. Ran `npm run eject`.
6. Opened up Xcode project and ran from inside. Console.logs() are still working.
7. Removed `localhost` entry from the `NSExceptionDomains`.
8. Edited scheme -> run -> changed from debug to release
9. Changed jsCodeLocation to `jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`
   Rebuilt app. Console.logs() no longer showing, but app loads.

This is at the point where the app is production ready, as per the guidelines of [React Native's Building Your App for Production](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hindsight, it probably makes sense that a production build wouldn't show console.logs(), but I'm still posting this in case it helps out anyone else.

If anyone, like me, wants to then get console.logs() back, it's as simple as doing the reverse of the tutorial. Follow these steps closely to return your app to a state where console.logs() will show:

1. In Xcode, Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> set Build Configuration to Debug
2. In your `AppDelegate.m`, change the `jsCodeLocation` to `jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];`
3. Finally, in your `Info.plist`, add the code below (use a text-editor for this - not Xcode - by right clicking and then choosing a text-editor of your choice):

Code:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Close all terminal windows, clean your project, close Xcode, close the simulator, and then launch Xcode again and rebuild your project. The console.logs() will be back.